# Powershell to get user attributes given samaaccount

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a notepad list of 100 users. Normally I use the below script to get all the users within one OU but this time I have users from different OU and I have to search using Samaccountname.

```
clear 
 $UserInfoFile = New-Item -type file -force "C:\Scripts\UserInfo.txt"  
"Login`tGivenname`tEmail" | Out-File $UserInfoFile -encoding ASCII 
 Import-CSV "C:\Scripts\OU.txt" | ForEach-Object { 
  $dn = $_.dn 
  $ObjFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(objectCategory=Person))" 
  $objSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
  $objSearch.PageSize = 15000 
  $objSearch.Filter = $ObjFilter 
  $objSearch.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$dn" 
  $AllObj = $objSearch.FindAll() 
foreach ($Obj in $AllObj) 
      { $objItemS = $Obj.Properties 
             $Ssamaccountname = $objItemS.samaccountname 
             $SsamaccountnameGN = $objItemS.givenname 
             $SsamaccountnameSN = $objItemS.sn 
             $SsamaccountnameEN = $objItemS.mail
             "$Ssamaccountname`t$SsamaccountnameGN`t$SsamaccountnameSN`t$SsamaccountnameEN" | Out-File $UserInfoFile -encoding ASCII -append 
      } # End of foreach
   } # End of ForEach-Object
```

I am trying to use the list of samaccountname to get the name and email of those users. I am new to Powershell so the above script itself was a bit difficult for me to grasp and now I am on an even more difficult task.

Comment: I suggest to use quest pssnapin: http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to filter the user list by account names you could do something like this:

```
$accounts = Get-Content userlist.txt

...

$objSearch.FindAll() | ? {
  $accounts -contains $_.Properties.sAMAccountName
} | % {
  "{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f ($_.Properties.givenname, $_.Properties.sn, $_.Properties.mail)
}
```

BTW, I'd recommend using the `ActiveDirectory` PowerShell module if possible. That will allow you to retrieve user accounts with a simple `Get-ADUser`, thus simplifying your code. The OU can be extracted from the user's distinguished name by splitting the dn at the first comma. Something like this:

```
$accounts = Get-Content userlist.txt
Get-ADUser * -Properties * | ? {
  $accounts -contains $_.Properties.sAMAccountName
} | select @{n="ou";e={($_.distinguishedName -split ",", 2)[1]}}, mail, givenName, sn, homeDirectory
```

or like this:

```
Get-Content userlist.txt | Get-ADUser -Properties * |
  select @{n="ou";e={($_.distinguishedName -split ",", 2)[1]}}, mail, givenName, sn, homeDirectory
```

Untested, though, since I don't have an AD at hand here.

Comment: I am using AD PowerShell module. I have a list of 100 samaccountname and I need to find their OU, email, name, home directory.

Comment: I got some error saying Unable to find default active directory server but I am sure your command there is flawless. What I ended up doing was I ran a command similar to yours on another AD tool and got a list of all the users with the email, name, samaccount, OU. Once I did that, I saved it in a textfile and ran some C# code on that textfile to get the records which matched with my Samaccounts. This worked for me as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it now but give this a try. You don't need to search AD if you know the user's DN. You can bind to it directly using the DN.

```
Import-CSV "C:\Scripts\OU.txt" | ForEach-Object { 
    $dn = $_.dn 
    $user = [adsi]"LDAP://$dn" 

    New-Object PSObject -Propertry @{ 
        samaccountname = $user.Properties['samaccountname']
        givenname = $user.Properties['givenname']
        sn = $user.Properties['sn']
        mail = $user.Properties['mail']
    }

} | Export-Csv $UserInfoFile
```

Comment: He doesn't have the distinguished names in this case, just a file with account names. The question is a bit misleading, since he posted code that he uses for a different task.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I did say, "Normally I use the below script to get all the users within one OU but this time I have users from different OU and I have to search using Samaccountname."